# What does it mean when the stack trace points to a line with no code?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with a *seemingly* distributed transaction:

> Exception Message: Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist
>   this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction. Other
>   Error:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Distributed
>   transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction
>   or the NULL transaction.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(String
>   commandText, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(String
>   sql, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(String sql, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   monk360.Data.Helpers.ChangeTrackingHelper.RecordUserConnection(DbContext
>   context, String userName) in
>   **d:\bld\9\117\Sources\Source\WEB\Source\monk360.Data\Helpers\ChangeTrackingHelper.cs:line
>   58**

Please pay close attention to the last line above:

**d:\bld\9\117\Sources\Source\WEB\Source\monk360.Data\Helpers\ChangeTrackingHelper.cs:line 58**

If we look at the code it shows that lien 58 *is just a blank line with no code:*

[image]

**What does it mean when the stack trace points to a line with no code?**

Comment: I wonder if there's a stale binary. You must have done the clean-solution-restart-VS-Rebuild-All routine?

Comment: Could you share the code of ChangeTrackingHelper.cs from line 50 to (at most) 70?

Answer (score 0):

it means your code is out of sync.  Clean>Rebuild then run again.  You may have to restart VS as well.